# Java: Executing cmd commands when running java file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Im doing some ssl socket programming in java, usually while running my program, I have to do it in cmd by executing the following commamd to tell it where the keystore is located:

> :java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password SSLServer

instead of

> java SSLServer

is there a way I can execute the above commands directly in eclipse rather than in cmd? Would the extra commands go as arguments(in the run configuration)? have tried this but it did not work.

Comment: I assume you mean `java SSLServer` - you don't execute the source file.

Comment: thats right, sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In run configuration there is a section for **VM Arguments**. These go there:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=.keystore 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

[image]